# Unity - Error CS106: Type 'Score' does not contain a definition for scoreUp

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

For the past couple of days I've been trying to make a simple flappy bird game. At the moment, I'm trying to write some code that will make the score go up every time the player passes through two pipes. I'm getting an error though, and I'm not too sure how to fix it. This is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Score : MonoBehaviour {

    public static int score = 0;

    private void Start() {
        score = 0;
    }

    private void Update() {
        GetComponent<UnityEngine.UI.Text>().text = score.ToString();
    }

    public void scoreUp() {
        score++;
    }
}
```

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class AddScore : MonoBehaviour {

    public Score score;
    
    private void OnTriggerEnter2D (Collider2D collision) {
        score.scoreUp(); // the line thats giving me problems
    }

}
```

The error I'm getting is: error CS1061: Type *Score* does not contain a definition for *scoreUp* and no extension method *scoreUp* of type *Score* could be found.

This doesn't make sense to me. Unity says 'The CS1061 error is caused when you try to call a method or access a class member that does not exist.'. But as can be seen in the code above, I DO have a class called Score and I DO have a method inside it called scoreUp().

Furthermore, I have used this kind of code before (where I created a class, used it and its method inside another class) without any problem. So I'm really not sure what the problem is in this specific scenario.

Comment: Your editor should show available methods when you type `score.`. Does it show `scoreUp`? Maybe there's another class called `Score` with absolutely another functionality (maybe it's a class from some of your external assets)

Comment: I suggest you cache the score UI object instead of looking for it each time in the Update fonction. To do so, define the Start method and then fetch it and save it locally.
`var scoreText = GetComponent<UnityEngine.UI.Text>();`

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`unityscript`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a JavaScript flavor like custom language used in early Unity versions and is long **deprecated** by now! Your code is clearly `c#` ... You should though use `unity3d` which is the main framework/API you are using here

Comment: Ate you sure it is referencing the correct `Score` type? Do you have multiple assemblies/namespaces etc? Are you sure there is no typo somewhere?

Comment: hi, did you find the solution. I am also facing the same error

Answer (score -1):

I think a solution to your issue would be to make the "AddScore" Class a child of "Score".

To make it a child simply change
AddScore : MonoBehaviour -> AddScore : Score

What you can do also instead of using public scoreUp() make it Protected so only the child class can access it.

your code should be something like this

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Score : MonoBehaviour {

    public static int score = 0;

    private void Start() {
        score = 0;
    }

    private void Update() {
        GetComponent<UnityEngine.UI.Text>().text = score.ToString();
    }

    protected void scoreUp() {
        score++;
    }
```

for the first bit and the second

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class AddScore : Score{

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D (Collider2D collision) {
        scoreUp();
    }

}
```